# onAttach method for being attached to a parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that can either be attached to an Activity or a parent fragment. This fragment has an interface that must be implemented by anyone it is attached to. For activities, this is quite simple:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        Activity activity =(Activity) context;
        try {
            mCallback = (OnMyListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() +
                " must implement OnMyListener");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to set the `mCallback` listener for other Fragments that are hosting this particular Fragment.

Comment: Check `getParentFragment()`. If it returns a non-null value, you're in another `Fragment`, and you can try casting that to your interface.

Comment: `getParentFragment()` returns null in my case. Is there a proper way to add a parent Fragment? I just inflate this Fragment in my Parent Fragment

Comment: how you are inflating/calling child fragment?

Comment: Oh never mind, I `getChildFragmentManager()` did the trick!

Comment: You should avoid fragment to fragment communication, use activity for communication b/w fragments.

Comment: Any reason not to? I have a reusable Fragment (basically a camera preview) that either belong to an Activity or a Fragment. I want its callbacks to trigger whomever is hosting it. If this is an antipattern I'd at least like a reason why

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly communicate between 2 fragments, it has to go thorough the activity hosting it (and I saw you already implemented the first half).

After the activity received the data from sender fragment, you can send it to the receiver fragment by resolving the receiver fragment's reference first, using:

```
ReceiverFragment fragment = ( ReceiverFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.receiver_fragment_id);
```

if it's null then you need to instantiate it first and pass the data using fragment.setArguments(Bundle), otherwise you can directly call the member function of the receiver fragment.

Check: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html